# Reconstructing {0: Array[1]} in the console

Tags: javascript

This might be an odd question, but I'm trying to find a format to pass data to a js function that I haven't written myself. When I print the data I want to study to the console I get the following:

```
Console.log(param[0]); // This prints "Object {0: Array[1]}"
```

Now, I want to pass my data to the this function and are trying to find the same format, which I can't seem to figure out.

The string in the log I'm trying to find looks like an array stored within an object so I've tried:

```
var val = 1000;
var data = {0:[val]};
console.log(data[0]); // prints "[1000]"

var val = 1000;
var data = new Object() {0:[val]};
console.log(data[0]); // prints "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

var val = 1000;
var data = [[val]];
console.log(data[0]); // prints "[1000]"

var val = 1000;
var data = [val], [val];
console.log(data[0]); // prints "Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in destructuring declaration"
```

Now, do anyone of you stars out there have any idea of how to reconstruct this message? I'm using Chrome if it matters.

Comment: Should be `var data = [{0:[val]}];`

Comment: why not log the function ?

Comment: JSON.stringify([{0:[val]}]); ? you will get string, not object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
var val = 1000;
var data = [{0: [val]}];
console.log(data[0]);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I had it wrong the other way around! I'll accept this answer as soon as I can. Thank you!

Comment: it may also be `var data = {0: {0: [val]}`

Comment: @Maxx I know, this is just a more compact (and likely) notation. Numerical keys aren't _typically_ on plain javascript objects, though it is possible.

Comment: @DaveLar Why do you need `data[0]`? It doesn't make much sense to have a custom structure just to print the first index of a hardcoded value.

Comment: @4castle I doubt this is for anything serious. The asker is probably just curious what sort of object resulted in a certain format when inspecting someone else's script, and wanted to reproduce said object.

Comment: @4castle I agree. It doesn't make sense to send one value like that. And it is like Patrick said. I wanted to know why it was sent that way by running the script